# Creating multiple columns from a single text column, sort of like a pivot

Tags: sql

This seems so simple to do, but I can't get the results I need...

I have a category, date, and a code:

```
Cat  Dt           Code
A    2013-07-02   X1
A    2013-07-02   Y4
A    2013-07-02   L2
A    2013-07-02   M8
A    2013-07-02   H7
A    2013-07-02   P4
```

and want to return it like this:

```
Cat   Dt           Code1   Code1   Code3   Code4   Code5   Code6
A     2013-07-02   X1      Y4      L2      M8      H7      P4
```

-- some sql to test with...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test1 (Cat VARCHAR(8), Dt DATE, Code VARCHAR(8) )

INSERT INTO dbo.test1 ( Cat, Dt, Code )

-- This set should return a value in all 6 Code columns...

SELECT 'A', '2013-07-02', 'X1'
UNION SELECT 'A', '2013-07-02', 'Y4'
UNION SELECT 'A', '2013-07-02', 'L2'
UNION SELECT 'A', '2013-07-02', 'M8'
UNION SELECT 'A', '2013-07-02', 'H7'
UNION SELECT 'A', '2013-07-02', 'P4'

-- This set should have a NULL in Code6 since there are only 5 codes

UNION SELECT 'B', '2013-07-03', 'Y6'
UNION SELECT 'B', '2013-07-03', 'D5'
UNION SELECT 'B', '2013-07-03', 'F8'
UNION SELECT 'B', '2013-07-03', 'G9'
UNION SELECT 'B', '2013-07-03', 'J2'

-- This set should have a NULL in Code6 since there are only 5 distinct codes

UNION SELECT 'C', '2013-07-04', 'D1'
UNION SELECT 'C', '2013-07-04', 'D1'
UNION SELECT 'C', '2013-07-04', 'U3'
UNION SELECT 'C', '2013-07-04', 'T9'
UNION SELECT 'C', '2013-07-04', 'G4'


-- This set has 7, but I only care about 6 of them. Which 6 doesn't matter, just any of the 6 codes

UNION SELECT 'D', '2013-07-05', 'T1'
UNION SELECT 'D', '2013-07-05', 'Y2'
UNION SELECT 'D', '2013-07-05', 'U3'
UNION SELECT 'D', '2013-07-05', 'I9'
UNION SELECT 'D', '2013-07-05', 'P8'
UNION SELECT 'D', '2013-07-05', 'L7'
UNION SELECT 'D', '2013-07-05', 'J6'
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the order of the values determining `Code1...Code6` ? Also, what RDBMS are you using (YYYY-MM-DD probably suggests MySQL although `dbo.` suggests MS SQL Server)

Comment: Sorry, order doesn't matter. There will rarely be more than 6, and if there is, I can discard any over 6. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way without using `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cat, Dt ORDER BY Cat, Dt)
    FROM dbo.test1
)
SELECT  Cat,
        Dt,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Code END) Code1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Code END) Code2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Code END) Code3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN Code END) Code4,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN Code END) Code5,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 6 THEN Code END) Code6
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Cat,
         Dt
```